# why is this a deadlock in golang / waitgroup?

Tags: go

I'm not sure what I'm missing but I get a deadlock error.  I'm using a buffered channel that I range over after all go routines complete. The channel has the capacity of 4 and I'm running 4 go routines so I'm expecting it to be "closed" automatically once it reaches the max capacity.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sync"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan []int, 4)
    var m []int

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            ch <- m
            return
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()

    for c := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("c is %v", c)
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you populate `m`?

Comment: That reminds me of http://stackoverflow.com/a/19892995/6309

Comment: The problem is `range ch` is still waiting for elements to come in the channel and there's no goroutine left to write on it.

Comment: I assume I'm sending an empty / zeroed slice. Even if I add ``m = append(m, i)`` before ``ch <- m`` it still gets into the deadlock. See http://play.golang.org/p/uAOnq6SdeR

Comment: `range`ing over a channel works if the channels gets closed which you are missing.

Comment: As @dystroy said, your range waits for the `ch` to be closed. You should add a `close(ch)` right after your `wg.Wait()`, otherwise `range ch` still expects inputs (which are not sent).

Comment: @Volker shouldn't the channel be closed automatically after the 4th iteration ?

Comment: @hey There's no reason for it to close.

Comment: ok then how can I fix it? It really doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @hey I made an answer so that it's clearer, see below

Answer (score 10):

You have two problems :

- there's not enough place for all the goroutines as your channel is too small : when your channel is full, the remaining goroutines must wait for a slot to be freed
- `range ch` is still waiting for elements to come in the channel and there's no goroutine left to write on it.

**Solution 1 :**

Make the channel big enough and, close it so that `range` stops waiting :

```
ch := make(chan []int, 5)
...
wg.Wait()
close(ch)
```

[Demonstration](http://play.golang.org/p/V1HBOTjARl)

This works but this mostly defeats the purpose of channels here as you don't start printing before all tasks are done.

**Solution 2 :**
This solution, which would allow a real pipelining (that is a smaller channel buffer), would be to do the `Done()` when printing :

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan []int, 4)
    var m []int

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            ch <- m
            return
        }()
    }
    go func() {
        for c := range ch {
            fmt.Printf("c is %v\n", c)
            wg.Done()
        }
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

[Demonstration](http://play.golang.org/p/iP8fm5DAD5)

Comment: why range ch is still waiting for elements if the channel is drained ? I assumed that once I send the 4th value the range reaches the end of "loop" so it should no longer wait for values.

Comment: `range` waits until the channel is closed. That's how it works. This way you can launch a goroutine and have it still work if you push elements into the channel later.

Comment: thanks for the answer , though it's curious because I have an app that does just the same thing except it doesn't go into deadlock. It loops through  some sql rows , launches go routines, I `wg.Wait()` after the for loop, range over the channel and  display the results of each routine. There is no "close(ch)" operation. I can only assume that the program itself goes into deadlock but I don't get the error.

Comment: Concerning the 2nd solution I'm not sure I understand but it still goes into deadlock except that the error is not thrown in ``main`` ?

Comment: sorry ... I think I've got how it works after all. Anyway shouldn't wg.Done() be after ``fmt.Printf("c is %v\n", c)`` http://play.golang.org/p/Be8eEc6PMu

Comment: @hey Yes. It is in my answer, I just mistyped it in the playground

Answer (score 9):

> I'm running 4 go routines

No, you're running 5 - thus the deadlock, as the channel buffers only 4 messages.

However, iterating over the channel will later on deadlock the program too. Since the channel isn't closed, it'll block forever once it read your 5 values.

So,

```
ch := make(chan []int, 5)
```

and

```
close(ch)
```

before the `range` loop.

Answer (score 1):

@Denys Séguret is right

but follow is anohter Solution easier to fix it:

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan []int, 4)
    var m []int

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            ch <- m
            return
        }()
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()
    for c := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("c is %v", c)
    }
}
```

form https://go.dev/blog/pipelines   Fan-out, fan-in 's func merge()

```
func merge(cs ...<-chan int) <-chan int {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    out := make(chan int)

    // Start an output goroutine for each input channel in cs.  output
    // copies values from c to out until c is closed, then calls wg.Done.
    output := func(c <-chan int) {
        for n := range c {
            out <- n
        }
        wg.Done()
    }
    wg.Add(len(cs))
    for _, c := range cs {
        go output(c)
    }

    // Start a goroutine to close out once all the output goroutines are
    // done.  This must start after the wg.Add call.
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try run this  code that don`t have wg ,and still deadlock ;
why?
Just because the main goroutine is blocked by the ch , so the program is suspended and timeout , and you get an deadlock error.
The essential reason is that ch is blocking the main goroutine.

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan []int, 4) // No matter which int number 
    var m []int
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go func() {
            ch <- m
            return
        }()
    }
    for c := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("c is %v \n", c)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a similar case to this, how can I fix it?