# fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock! goroutine 1 [semacquire]:

Tags: go

I'm running goroutine and its channels I still get errors

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func foo(c chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    c <- 45
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 4)
    c <- 122
    wg.Done()

}

func main() {
    canal := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(2)
    go foo(canal,&wg)
    go foo(canal,&wg)
    wg.Wait()

    for a := range canal {
        fmt.Println(a)
    }

}
```

Comment: Duplicate: [why is this a deadlock in golang / waitgroup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609395/why-is-this-a-deadlock-in-golang-waitgroup)

Comment: not the same problem ....

Comment: @dılosürücü, it is: some number of goroutines that send to a channel, and the calling goroutine calling WaitGroup.Wait before ranging over the channel. Everything else are details that don't change the problem (or its solution).

Answer (score 1):

`make(chan int)` creates an [unbuffered channel](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types). This means that all send and receive operators wait until the other side is ready.

The moment you call `c <- 45` in a goroutine, that goroutine will wait until someone receives from the channel. But no consumer exists until the `range canal` statement which is stuck behing `wg.Wait()`.

So your two goroutines are stuck sending to the channel and main is waiting for the goroutines to be finished before consuming from the channel.

You can either consume elements from the channel in a separate goroutine (before `wg.Wait()`), or create a buffered channel (eg: `make(chan int, 10)`.